# What is the textbook used to learn Chinese in Havard and MIT?

Tags: learning, resources

I know that Havard has an excellent East Culture Research center but what about the teaching of Chinese there?

Comment: Are you just asking about the textbook, or are you also asking about the quality of the teaching? If it's the latter, you're better off reading reviews elsewhere (since information like this depends on who's teaching and will become out of date and not very useful). If it's the former, it still might depend on the exact course. I know people who use _Integrated Chinese_, but they're not at Harvard.

Comment: By the way, it will also depend a lot on the specific class. _Integrated Chinese_ seems popular, but I doubt it would be appropriate to classical Chinese classes or "Chinese for business".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about introductory level stuff.

- MIT: For complete beginners: [Integrated Chinese](https://www.cheng-tsui.com/browse/integrated-chinese)

  Sources: http://web.mit.edu/gsl/syllabi/21G.101-Syllabus.pdf (Fall 2013)

  For people who have some level of speaking ability: [Learning Chinese: A Foundation Course in Mandarin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300141173) (a book made by MIT instructors) and [A Primer for Advanced Beginners of Chinese, Simplified Characters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0231125550)

  Source: http://web.mit.edu/gsl/syllabi/21G.107-Syllabus.pdf (Fall 2015)
- Harvard: Complete beginners: Also [Integrated Chinese](https://www.cheng-tsui.com/browse/integrated-chinese)

  Couldn't find any info on heritage learner's textbook.

  Source: http://harvardcoopbooks.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBWizardView?storeId=52084 and searching for `Fall2015 Chin E 1 01`